# stringstream serialization, on centOS, of large set of floats is faster than 4 pthread-ts which serialize chunks. std::threads are faster on Windows

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have the task to optimize the serialization of large sets of floats on a hard-disk.
My initial approach has the following:

```
class StringStreamDataSerializer
{
public:
void serializeRawData(const vector<float>& data);
void saveToFileStream(std::fstream&  file);
private:
stringstream _stringStream;
};

void StringStreamDataSerializer::serializeRawData(const vector<float>& data)
{
for (float currentFloat : data)
    _stringStream << currentFloat;
}

void StringStreamDataSerializer::saveToFileStream(std::fstream&  file)
{
file << _stringStream.str().c_str();
file.close();   
}
```

I wanted to separate the task of serializaton between 4 threads, to make the 
serialization faster. Here's how:

```
struct st_args
{
const vector<float>* data;
size_t from;
size_t to;
size_t segment;
} ;

string outputs[4];
std::mutex g_display_mutex;
void serializeLocal(void *context)
{
 struct st_args *readParams = (st_args*)context;

 for (auto i = readParams->from; i < readParams->to; i++)
 {
     string currentFloat = std::to_string( readParams->data->at(i));

     currentFloat.erase(currentFloat.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, 
     std::string::npos);
     outputs[readParams->segment] += currentFloat;
 }
 }

void SImplePThreadedSerializer::serializeRawData(const vector<float>& data)
{
const int N = 4;
size_t totalFloats = data.size();
st_args* seg;
pthread_t* chunk;

chunk = (pthread_t *) malloc(N*sizeof(pthread_t));
seg   = (st_args *) malloc(N*sizeof(st_args));

size_t from = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    seg[i].from = 0;
    seg[i].data = &data;
}

int i = 0;
for (; i < N - 1; ++i)
{
    seg[i].from = from;
    seg[i].to = seg[i].from + totalFloats / N;
    seg[i].segment = i;

    pthread_create(&chunk[i], NULL, (void *(*)(void *)) serializeLocal, 
(void *) &(seg[i]));
    from += totalFloats / N;
}

seg[i].from = from;
seg[i].to = totalFloats;
seg[i].segment = i;

pthread_create(&chunk[i], NULL, (void *(*)(void *)) serializeLocal, (void *) 
&(seg[i]));

size_t totalBuffered = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
{
    pthread_join(chunk[k], NULL);
    totalBuffered += outputs[k].size();
}
str.reserve(totalBuffered);
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
{
   str+= outputs[k];
}

free(chunk);
free(seg);
}
```

Turns out, that the stringstream is faster even from 4 thread on Linux. On Windows I am archiving an optimization with the presented approach (with std::thread) on Windows, but on Linux I have the opposite results. Any explanation why would be helpful and appreciated.

Here are the results on centOS:
*** Serialization of 10000000 floats on the hard disk *** 
StringStreamDataSerializer flushes data in file in 0.55 seconds.
StringStreamDataSerializer Finished in 3.28 seconds.
SImplePThreadedSerializer flushes data in file in 0.46 seconds.
SImplePThreadedSerializer Finished in 6.96 seconds.

On windows, the multithreaded serialization is done by 4 std::threads and they actually optimize the serialization:

```
static void serializeChunk(string& output, const vector<float>& data, size_t 
from, size_t to)
{
for (auto i = from; i < to; i++)
{
    string currentFloat = std::to_string(data[i]);

    //fuckin trim the zeroes at the end
    currentFloat.erase(currentFloat.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, 
std::string::npos);
    output += currentFloat;
}
}

void SimpleMultiThreadedSerializer::serializeRawData(const vector<float>& 
data)
{

const int N = 4;
thread t[N]; // say, 4 CPUs.
string outputs[N];
size_t totalFloats = data.size();

size_t from = 0;

int i = 0;
for (; i < N - 1; ++i)
{
    t[i] = thread(serializeChunk, std::ref(outputs[i]), data, from, from + 
totalFloats / N);
    from += totalFloats / N;
}
t[i] = thread(serializeChunk, std::ref(outputs[i]), data, from, 
totalFloats);

for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    t[i].join();

size_t totalBuffered = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    totalBuffered += outputs[i].size();

str.reserve(totalBuffered);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    str += outputs[i];
}
```

And the results:
*** Serialization of 1000000 floats on the hard disk ***
StringStreamDataSerializer flushes data in file in 0.116 seconds.
StringStreamDataSerializer Finished in 10.236 seconds.

SimpleMultiThreadedSerializer flushes data in file in 0.105 seconds.
SimpleMultiThreadedSerializer Finished in 3.01 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion between binary floating point and decimal output is very expensive.  If performance is a concern, you should serialize the data in binary (possibly after endianess conversion, so you get at least interoperability across IEEE 754 systems).

Regarding the poor threading on GNU/Linux performance, this is like a [known performance issue regarding locale object handling](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71430).  In multi-threaded mode, `stringstream` currently uses a process-wide, heavily contended reference counter for locale handling.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I think I understand the issue. I will try to implement and use ftoa method, which either will get a locale object and maybe lock it or doesn't use such at all.